# Wso2 connector deployment

Tags: wso2

I'm new to WSO2. I'm working on one of the API that use email connector/registry artifacts. I can run the project successfully on my local machine without any issue.

The API's are deployed using the following line in the docker file  to the server

COPY src/main/synapse-config/ /home/wso2carbon/wso2mi-4.0.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/

When I deployed my API, I don't know where to copy the connector/registry artifacts. My API always give me an error for the connector.
I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Copying synapse artifacts directly is not the correct way. It would be best if you created a deployable archive and copy it to the container. Refer to this document. https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/develop/packaging-artifacts/

Once the Carbon archive is made you can copy it to wso2carbon/wso2mi-4.0.0/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps directory in the container.

Also, you can use maven to build this.